# Problematic Quotes in Javascript callFunction()

Tags: javascript, htmlspecialchars

I would like to know how to maintain the ability to have both single and double quotes in text that I am passing to a JavaScript function with callFunction()? All three cases below appears to be failing.

Mixing the single and double quotes will work but I would like to be able to use both single and double quotes in my text blocks. It is curious why the browser is evaluating html special characters before passing it to the Javascript function.

Thanks, Robin

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function callFunction(text){

    alert(text);

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<!--This will not work due to &#039;-->
<a href="javascript: callFunction('Robin&#039;s Text')">Robin&#039;s Text</a> 

<br />
<br />

<!--And this will not work due to &#034;-->
<a href='javascript: callFunction("Robin&#034;s Text")'>Robin&#034;s Text</a>

<br />
<br />

<!--Trying with a slash but not working either-->
<a href='javascript: callFunction("Robin\'s Text")'>Robin's Text</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `&#039;` is the HTML escape code, you need to use the JS one `\u0027` (note the change from dec to hex)

Comment: @david, no OP just needs to use the correct escape characters in JavaScript followed by the correct HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your advice. With it, I have found a workable solution. It appears that using both backslash and HTML Special Characters together will allow it to work. I am not sure why both is required?

```
<!--Using HTML Special Characters (&#039;) alone will not work-->
<a href="#" onClick="callFunction('Robin&#039;s Text')">Robin&#039;s Text</a>

<br />
<br />

<!--Using backslash (\) alone will not work-->
<a href="javascript: callFunction('Robin\"s Text')">Robin"s Text</a>

<br />
<br />

<!--But using a combination of both will work!-->
<a href="javascript: callFunction('Robin\&#034;s Text')">Robin"s Text</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the input for the JS function will be machine-generated, then you should escape the input from the server, then unescape it in the client-side as below:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick='callFunction("Robin%27s%20Text")'>Robin's Text</a>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick='callFunction("Robin%22s%20Text")'>Robin"s Text</a>
```

JS:

```
function callFunction(text){
    alert(decodeURIComponent(text));
}
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8y4JE/1/)

Comment: When someone has a problem understanding encoding, please don't ever suggest adding another layer of encoding. It's bad enough that OP is trying to HTML encode a JavaScript string, don't make things worse by adding percent encoding into the mix as well.

Comment: Please read the assumption for the suggested solution: "Assuming that the input for the JS function will be machine-generated, ..."

Comment: So what you're saying is that if the code is programmatically generated you should ignore the bugs in how the code is generated and add an extra unnecessary layer of encoding? No, that's exactly what I disagree with. If the code is being generated, fix it so that it's piped through the correct encoder before being output as an attribute value.

Comment: What would be your preferred encoding in such case?

Comment: The contents of the javascript string must be correctly escaped, and then the javascript string itself must be correctly HTML encoded. That is all.

Comment: I believe that we are talking about the same solution here. :)

Comment: `decodeURIComponent` is percent encoding, and unrelated to JavaScript escaping and HTML encoding. I don't believe we are talking about the same thing.

Comment: Then which JS encoding method would you suggest here?

Comment: Comments aren't the place for extended discussion. I thought [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23191683/497418) was clear enough to explain this concept, but apparently there are at least two people who disagree, so let me know if you still have questions.