# String doesn't work with double & single quotes

Tags: javascript

In my code i have a JavaScript function that has a line like below:

```
var header = "<a href='javascript:SortTable(0,'T');'>Name</a>";
```

For some reason this doesn't work. I think the problem is the single or double quotes in the string.

The idea is to insert this **header** as a column header in a table with a clickable link. The issue is, ('T') doesn't work here. I want to call the JS function **SortTable** with a **integer** and **character** argument.

I tried the below with escape character and that too doesn't work.

```
var header = "<a href='javascript:SortTable(0,\'T\');\'>ATO</a>";
```

How can make this long string properly work?

Comment: escape them by using `\'` instead of `'`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23191193/497418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
var header = "<a href='javascript:SortTable(0,\"T\");'>ATO</a>";
```

---

> For some reason this doesn't work. I think the problem is the single or double quotes in the string.

Yes. Consider the HTML that is generated:

```
<a href='javascript:SortTable(0,'T');'>Name</a>
//      ^                       ^
//    start                    end
```

You can even see it through the syntax highlight. Now, escaping it via `\` doesn't work either. `\` is the escape characters JS strings. `\'` becomes `'`, so you get the same result.

But even `\\'` wouldn't help because `\` is not an escape character in HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the record, another thing that'll work is

```
var header = "<a href='javascript:SortTable(0,&quot;T&quot;);'>ATO</a>";
```

JavaScript won't pay attention to the HTML entity notation, but when that stuff is added to the document the HTML parser will.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
var header = "<a href=\"javascript:SortTable(0,'T');\">ATO</a>";
```

For

```
<a href="javascript:SortTable(0,'T');">ATO</a>
```

Comment: This is the solution I like best because it creates the cleanest HTML. It bothers me when HTML markup uses single quotes in attributes and then double quotes in the inline JavaScript.